# Illegal dynamic reference

Tags: sbt

```
jniPath := {
    val subProjectPath = projectDependencies.value map (module => (jniPath in LocalProject(module.name)).value)

    val path = libraryDependencies.value flatMap (_.name)

    path ++ subProjectPath mkString File.pathSeparator
}
```

Does anyone have a workaround? It seems that the issue is coming from the `(jniPath in LocalProject(module.name)).value` but I can't see any way to do so is this a limitation of SBT?

Cheers

Comment: This answer may be very relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50436200/5704808

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Cheers for the answers, I solved my issue by using `key.all(ScopeFilter(in))` in a `Def.taskDyn`:

```
jniPaths := jniPathsImpl(inDependencies(ThisProject))
def jniPathsImpl(in: ScopeFilter.ProjectFilter) = Def.taskDyn {
   ivyJniPath.all(ScopeFilter(in)) map { ivyJniPaths =>
     libraryDependencies.value flatMap (_.name)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

you'll need to define your work in a dynamic task http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Tasks.html#Dynamic+Computations+with which allows you to define your Task's dependencies based on things that are not well-defined at compile time.

Remember, in sbt all tasks are really a map from their dependencies to the result and any time your type `thing.value` you're really writing `(thing).map { valueOfThing => ... }` once the macro has its wicked way.

Answer (score 1):

As fommil wrote [dynamic task](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Tasks.html#Dynamic+Computations+with) is the way to go.

To understand why take a look at [Execution semantics of tasks](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Custom-Settings.html#Execution+semantics+of+tasks):

> Unlike plain Scala method calls, invoking `value` method on tasks will not be evaluated strictly. Instead, they simply act as placeholders to denote that `sampleIntTask` depends on `startServer` and `stopServer` tasks.

Because dependent tasks are scheduled *before* the curly brace of the task begins, you can't use the result from another task to scope another task.