# sbt - Illegal dynamic reference

Tags: scala, dynamic, build, sbt

Below is the code that is used inside my build.sbt to add additional test source directories and it works fine :-

```
unmanagedSourceDirectories in Test ++= Seq ( (baseDirectory( _ / "abc" )).value, (baseDirectory( _ / "xyz" )).value )
```

But, following version gives **Illegal dynamic error**

```
val folderList = Seq("abc", "xyz")
unmanagedSourceDirectories in Test ++= folderList map { src => (baseDirectory( _ / src )).value }
```

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34162484/illegal-dynamic-reference), i tried Dynamic tasks also with no luck :-

```
val folderList = Seq("abc", "xyz")
val dynamic = Def.taskDyn{
  Def.task{
    folderList
  }
}
unmanagedSourceDirectories in Test ++= dynamic.value map { src => (baseDirectory( _ / src )).value }
```

Kindly suggest the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to define a dynamic task for this use case. Simply use the `.value` macro:

```
val folderList = Seq("abc", "xyz")
unmanagedSourceDirectories in Test ++=
  folderList.map { src => (baseDirectory in Test).value / src }
```

Comment: It worked for me. But, what was wrong in the syntax, that i have used. any reference/details for sbt newbies like me is much appreciated.